# R scraping when URL is Redirected (302)

Tags: r, redirect, rcurl, scraper

R related problem and I am quite new to R

I am running a scraper on the movie database but at least one URL is redirected to another page.

Do you have any idea how I could follow the URL and scrape the redirected site instead.

I've been getting the XML by using this method

```
require(XML) 
require(RCurl) 
fixedURL <- getURL("https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/260346-taken-3/cast")
parsed.html <- htmlParse(fixedURL)
```

Could also use the scrapeR package if that would help.

but the URL is redirected (302) to "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/260346-tak3n/cast"
Any Ideas how I can make it follow the redirection? (It is a part of a loop and there are very few redirections.)

Comment: add `followlocation=TRUE` to `getURL()`.

Comment: I am quicker implementing this method than using rvest. Thank you Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rvest package seems to land on the correct page...

```
library("rvest")
url <- "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/260346-taken-3/cast"
# get movie title
url %>% 
  html() %>% 
  html_nodes("#mainCol :nth-child(1) :nth-child(1) :nth-child(1) :nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text()

[1] "Taken 3"
```

Comment: Very nice (Two thumbs up).
Works perfectly, gonna read up on rvest now, never looked into that. 

Thank you very much.